# ArrayBuffer of Strings - Min

Tags: scala, sorting, arraybuffer

I have the following code inside a `scalatest` Spec:

```
val arr = ArrayBuffer("Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb")
arr.max shouldEqual "little"
arr.min shouldEqual "a"
```

Which **fails** on the second `shouldEqual`, saying:

`"[Mary]" did not equal "[a]"`

Why does this not return `"a"`?

According to **Scala for the Impatient, 2nd ed.**: "...the `min` and `max` methods yield the smallest and largest element in an array or array buffer."

*Horstmann, Cay S.. Scala for the Impatient (Kindle Locations 1515-1517). Pearson Education. Kindle Edition.*

Postface: When book says "...yields the *smallest* and *largest*..." it means ASCII comparison, not the length as in implemented in the chosen answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On ascii table, upper case letters come before lower case letters, so `Mary < a` and is the smallest element, you can check this in the scala REPL:

```
scala> "Mary" < "a"
// res4: Boolean = true
```

---

If you need to compare by the number of characters in the string, you can use `minBy` and `maxBy` to compare strings by their sizes:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val arr = ArrayBuffer("Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb")
// arr: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer(Mary, had, a, little, lamb)

arr.minBy(_.size)
// res5: String = a

arr.maxBy(_.size)
// res6: String = little
```

Comment: If you want to get `a` for the min, you can do `arr.map(_.toLowerCase)` to ensure you only have lower case letters.

Comment: but then `max` will be `"mary"`